# Backward error of solving $Ax=b$ with perturbed matrix $A$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, matrix-analysis

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-0.55 \\ 
-2 & 1.06
\end{bmatrix}, b=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix}$. How to compute the **backward error** of the algorithm of solving $Ax=b$, with respect to perturbation in the
matrix? Here I perturb matrix $A$ to get
$A'=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\delta &-0.55 \\ 
-2 & 1.06
\end{bmatrix}$, where $0<\delta<1$.